# Azure Databricks, Python - convert json column string to dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Azure Databricks and Python 3.

I have a data frame (df1) with a column called 'BodyJson' which is of 'string' data type.

'BodyJson' is a complex json structure - an example is shown below of one row from (df1).

**Column BodyJson From df1**

```json
{
  "Timestamp": 3690414400,
  "Sender": "10.99.45.6:32768:wifivm0002EF",
  "Type": "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.599.0.8",
  "CaptureTime": 637616722902708244,
  "Variables": [
    {
      "Key": "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.513.1.2.1.1.1.0",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "Key": "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.513.1.1.1.1.5.200.249.249.41.0.128",
      "Value": {
        "Hex": "66696E7362792D7761703033",
        "String": "123456-wap03"
      }
    },
    {
      "Key": "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.599.1.3.2.1.2.0",
      "Value": 1
    },
    {
      "Key": "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.599.1.3.2.1.3.0",
      "Value": {
        "Hex": "0A9603F4",
        "String": "\n?\u0003?"
      }
    },
    {
      "Key": "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.599.1.3.1.1.27.114.154.56.22.154.160",
      "Value": {
        "Hex": "766D6564776966692F646965676F33756B407961686F6F2E636F6D",
        "String": "vmedwifi/xxxuk@yahoo.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "Key": "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.599.1.3.1.1.28.114.154.56.22.154.160",
      "Value": {
        "Hex": "56697267696E204D65646961",
        "String": "Virgin Media"
      }
    },
    {
      "Key": "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.599.1.3.1.1.38.114.154.56.22.154.160",
      "Value": {
        "Hex": "36306562663133322F37323A39613A33383A31363A39613A61302F3931323639363136",
        "String": "60ebf132/72:9a:38:16:9a:a0/91269616"
      }
    },
    {
      "Key": "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.599.1.3.1.1.8.114.154.56.22.154.160",
      "Value": {
        "Hex": "C8F9F9290080",
        "String": "???)\u0000?"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The only part of 'BodyJson' I am interested in is called "Variables" which holds a array of json rows. These rows come in two forms - examples forms with example values shown below:

**Form-1**

```json
{
  "Key": "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.513.1.2.1.1.1.0",
  "Value": "1"
}
```

**Form-2**

```json
{
  "Key": "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.513.1.1.1.1.5.200.249.249.41.0.128",
  "Value": {
    "Hex": "66696E7362792D7761703033",
    "String": "123456-wap03"
  }
}
```

I would like to create a two new data frames that can hold rows of either form-1 or form-2 - for example the columns would be...

**New Data Frame holding only Form-1 rows...**

- Key(string)    = "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.513.1.2.1.1.1.0"
- Value(string)  = "1"

**New Data Frame holding only Form-2 rows**...

- Key(string)   - "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.513.1.1.1.1.5.200.249.249.41.0.128"
- Value(string) - "123456-wap03" (Popualated with values from "Value"."String". NB: I am not interested in values from "Value"."Hex")

How do I go about extracting the data from the column 'BodyJson' and create 2 new data frames?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to transform your JSON column into another dataframe. To do it, transform your `BodyJson` into RDD and read using `spark.read.json`.

After it, to identifying which rows has a JSON you can use `get_json_object` and select `$.String`. Case a row doesn't have it, will return as null.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ["""{"Timestamp":3690414400,"Sender":"10.99.45.6:32768:wifivm0002EF","Type":"1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.599.0.8","CaptureTime":637616722902708244,"Variables":[{"Key":"1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.513.1.2.1.1.1.0","Value":"1"},{"Key":"1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.513.1.1.1.1.5.200.249.249.41.0.128","Value":{"Hex":"66696E7362792D7761703033","String":"123456-wap03"}},{"Key":"1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.599.1.3.2.1.2.0","Value":1},{"Key":"1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.599.1.3.2.1.3.0","Value":{"Hex":"0A9603F4","String":"\n?\u0003?"}},{"Key":"1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.599.1.3.1.1.27.114.154.56.22.154.160","Value":{"Hex":"766D6564776966692F646965676F33756B407961686F6F2E636F6D","String":"vmedwifi/xxxuk@yahoo.com"}},{"Key":"1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.599.1.3.1.1.28.114.154.56.22.154.160","Value":{"Hex":"56697267696E204D65646961","String":"Virgin Media"}},{"Key":"1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.599.1.3.1.1.38.114.154.56.22.154.160","Value":{"Hex":"36306562663133322F37323A39613A33383A31363A39613A61302F3931323639363136","String":"60ebf132/72:9a:38:16:9a:a0/91269616"}},{"Key":"1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.599.1.3.1.1.8.114.154.56.22.154.160","Value":{"Hex":"C8F9F9290080","String":"???)\u0000?"}}]}"""]
], schema='BodyJson string')

rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.BodyJson)
body_df = spark.read.json(rdd, allowUnquotedControlChars=True)

variables_df = body_df.selectExpr('inline(Variables)')
variables_df = variables_df.withColumn('ObjValue', f.get_json_object('Value', '$.String'))

form_1_df = variables_df.where(f.col('ObjValue').isNull())
form_1_df = form_1_df.drop('ObjValue')
display(form_1_df)

form_2_df = variables_df.where(f.col('ObjValue').isNotNull())
form_2_df = form_2_df.select('Key', f.col('ObjValue').alias('Value'))
display(form_2_df)
```

First output:

[image: form_1_df]

Second output:

[image: form_2_df]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. Your code and answer were spot on! Thanks very much